# How to disable Spring boot validation factory

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

In my Spring boot application:

1. there is a **third party** jar that contains older version of javax.validation library
2. there is also Spring boot **default** javax.validation library (1.1.0.Final) that comes with hibernate-validator (5.3.5.Final)

My code builds properly. However, fails during startup with following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:331)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor$ValidatedLocalValidatorFactoryBean.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.getValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:368)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.determineValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 63 more
```

It is clear from log that `ConfigurationState.getParameterNameProvider()` method is not found, and that is due to clash between validation-api versions. I know Hibernate-validator needs new version of validation-api (1.1.0) but Spring is somehow picking up older version of validation-api classes which is present in third party jar.

I can't remove old version of validation-api classes from my build process, as they come inbuilt with **third party** jar that I need for other purpose.

I tried couple of options:

`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration`

and

`spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none` in `application.properties` but none of them worked.

Is there a way in Spring boot to disable `buildValidatorFactory` or `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` to avoid this error?

Comment: try using the exclude parameter of the Autoconfiguration or SpringBootApplication annotations like so:  `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=buildValidatorFactory.class)` or `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = buildValidatorFactory.class)` and see if that makes a difference

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication(exclude=ConfigurationImpl.class)
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=HibernateValidator.class)
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=LocalValidatorFactoryBean.class)`

Tried all above options, but no change in behaviour.


Tried the same classes with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` as well, but no change.

Comment: You can esclude the not needed versions inyour `pom`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the following solution helped:

> ValidatorFactoryBeanWithDisabledValidation.java

```
@Component
@Primary
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.custom.beans", name = "validator-factory-with-disabled-validation")
public class ValidatorFactoryBeanWithDisabledValidation extends OptionalValidatorFactoryBean {
    @Override
    public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validate(final T object, final Class<?>... groups) {
        return Set.of();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateProperty(final T object,
                                                            final String propertyName,
                                                            final Class<?>... groups) {
        return Set.of();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateValue(final Class<T> beanType,
                                                         final String propertyName,
                                                         final Object value,
                                                         final Class<?>... groups) {
        return Set.of();
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(final Object target, final Errors errors) {
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(final Object target, final Errors errors, final Object... validationHints) {
    }

    @Override
    public void validateValue(final Class<?> targetType,
                              final String fieldName,
                              final Object value,
                              final Errors errors,
                              final Object... validationHints) {
    }
}
```

> application.properties

```
spring.custom.beans.validator-factory-with-disabled-validation=true
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration
```

i using spring-boot 2.1.2.RELEASE version without hibernate.

Comment: in my case it was enough just to add this one line `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration` to turn off validation from Spring